# Problems in remote threads synchronization in two Java Android applications

Tags: java, android, synchronization, java-threads, tcpsocket

I have a problem with syncing two android apps exchanging data via TCP Socket using **OutputStream** and **InputStream**. By trying the two apps on the **same smartphone**, the data is sent and read in the **correct order** and all works fine. But if the devices on which the two apps run are **different**, the data are sent (or read) in a different order than expected and therefore I cannot use them for subsequent operations.

This is the part of the **sender** thread that sends the data, where "output_client" is an instance of OutputStream:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){

       byte[] cert_byte = certs[i].getEncoded();
       output_client.write(ByteBuffer.allocate(4).putInt(cert_byte.length).array());
       output_client.flush();

       output_client.write(cert_byte);
       output_client.flush();
}
```

This is the part of the **receiver** thread that receives the data, where "inputStream" is an instance of InputStream:

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++){

    inputStream.read(lenByte);
    len = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenByte).getInt();
    byte[] certByte = new byte[len];

    inputStream.read(certByte);

    [...]
}
```

As seen particularly in the receiver, the order in which data is read from the inputStream is important.
My problem is that the second inputStream.read() doesn't read the expected data and I can't figured out why. I've tried to implement some basics synchronization mechanism but nothing works.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your main problem is that incoming data may be fragmented or incomplete. The standard `read` command only reads data up to the size of the buffer but in worst case it can be just one byte. If you know by your protocol that e.g. 150 bytes will follow you should use DataInputStream and use a `new byte[150]` and `readFully` instead of `read`. That will ensure all 150 bytes are read before Java continues execution.